# Gate closer for metal gate

Tags: gates

What type of gate closer should I use for my metal garden gate? It is about waist high. I'm just looking for something simple -- if it was a wooden gate, I would just use a gate spring.

Please note, I'm not looking for a product recommendation -- just advice on how you would get this gate to close. And maybe the type (but not make) of gate closer you would use (if some types work better than others on metal gates).

[image: gate]

Comment: I don't see what the door material has to do with the spring type. There are plenty of spring closers for metal gates. What problem have you encountered finding one?

Comment: I assumed gate springs were for wooden gates. How would I connect this one to my gate: https://www.screwfix.com/p/gate-spring-black-200mm/17251

Comment: Lots of options involving mounting bars or tabs, U-clamps, etc. It's a matter of aesthetics.

Comment: I'm not concerned with aesthetics, but gate closers I have seen need a bigger surface on the gate to attach to. Can you send me a link to an example that would fit on my gate.

Comment: The one you posted would work fine. Like I said, mounting tabs. You could attach a small L-bracket to the bottom bar of your gate and mount the spring to that. DIY is about some degree of creativity. Time to shine!

Comment: I like the colonial-period closers that use a counter-weight instead of a spring; they close a bit more gently and don't wear out as quickly.

Comment: I can't imagine that _any_ gate closer _wouldn't_ close this gate. The only restrictions are in figuring out how to mount it. Something designed to screw into a wooden gate could be mounted to this one by putting a metal plate on either side of the gate and bolting through both plates & the mount, or by welding a mounting plate to the gate itself. This then, comes down to which one _you_ like, and that an opinion and that's off-topic too. Please edit to indicate what we can answer for you that _isn't_ an opinion and I'll retract the VtC.

Comment: If you're looking for a "how do I attach this closer to my gate", then please ask that instead.